# How to custom the format display of post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new in Wordpress. I would like to know how to custom the format display of post in Wordpress. I want to make a different presentation for each post base on the category. It's a short post with a minimum description and thumbnail for viewing at home page, not a full post.
Is there any way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: do you want to customize the details page of a post, or the overview? details page is the "single.php" template in your theme and the overview page is the "index,php" template in your theme folder...copy it to a child theme and make your changes

Comment: The overview. Then the right way is to make a child theme?

Comment: yes, because your changes will be deleted if you make an theme update...generate an child theme, and copy the index.php from your parent theme to your child theme and make your changes in the child theme...